# How to avoid exposing my MAC address when using IPv6?

Tags: ipv6, privacy, mac-address

On my Macs, each IPv6 address [includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Address_Format) the MAC address of a specific computer (*not* of my router). Sites such as [ipv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com/) not only show it, but even tell me it belongs to an Apple computer.

This feels like a super cookie, and might apply to other operating systems as well. How can I avoid my MAC addresses from being exposed?

Background: the MAC address is [not in plain sight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64). Like for `2001:0db8:1:2:60:8ff:fe52:f9d8`:

- Take the last 64 bits (the host identifier) and add leading zeroes: `0060:08ff:fe52:f9d8`.
- Strip the `ff:fe` part from the middle. If these bytes are not there, [then](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#page-20) there's no MAC address.
- For the first byte: complement the second low-order bit (the universal/local bit; if the bit is a 1, make it 0, and if it is a 0, make it 1). So: `0x00` (00000000) becomes `0x02` (00000010).
- Presto: `60:8ff:fe52:f9d8` translates back to MAC address `02:60:08:52:f9:d8`.

---

Note: since macOS 10.12 Sierra, according to Ars Technica [Apple has adopted a new way of generating stable addresses that are not based on a MAC address](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/09/macos-10-12-sierra-the-ars-technica-review/6/), which Windows apparently had already been doing for years.

---

> This question was a **[Super User Question of the Week](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week)**.
> Read the **[blog entry](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/02/11/did-you-know-that-ipv6-may-include-your-mac-address-heres-how-to-stop-it/)** for more details or **[contribute to the blog](http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/)** yourself

Comment: Wow I did not know that about IPV6, nice find.

Comment: Well, of course it shows an Apple computer. It is a MAC address, after all.

Comment: @Kronos, an image has gone missing on the blog entry; http://blog.superuser.com/2011/02/11/did-you-know-that-ipv6-may-include-your-mac-address-heres-how-to-stop-it/ Adding ".stack" to the URL helps: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RNXoA.png

Comment: ...but, @KronoS, adding ".stack" actually makes another image form that same blog post disappear, like http://i.imgur.com/vjK73.png (okay) vs http://i.stack.imgur.com/vjK73.png (not okay). In other words: maybe *all* images on the blog that do not currently use `.stack` should be re-uploaded...?

Comment: @Arjan I'm not sure.  I'm going to have to check into this.  I would like for a feature that all images uploaded to the blog are automatically uploaded to stack's imgur account.  Similar to what the regular sites do currently

Comment: @Arjan - nice work

Comment: This is why I don't trust IPv6.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

This is solved by two extensions to IPv6:

- [RFC 4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941) aka "Privacy Addressing" lets outbound connections use temporary, randomly generated addresses (which are rotated every few hours).
- [RFC 7217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7217) allows the primary, static address to be generated from an opaque hash which does not reveal any information.

At least one but increasingly both methods are supported by popular operating systems.

Note that these features are orthogonal. You can use both at the same time, if you want to.

#### Stable private addresses

In some operating systems, the primary interface identifier is no longer generated from MAC or EUI-64 – instead it is generated using a hash or random seed (usually according to [RFC 7217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7217))

This kind of address is still static *per network* – the same OS on the same machine within the same IPv6 prefix should always generate the same suffix. It is suitable for incoming connections.

- **Windows** beginning with Windows Vista uses a custom scheme, and beginning with Windows 11 uses the RFC 7217 scheme (if I remember correctly).

  To check if the feature is active, run a PowerShell command:

  ```
  Get-NetIPv6Protocol | fl RandomizeIdentifiers
  ```

  To enable/disable the feature:

  ```
  Set-NetIPv6Protocol -RandomizeIdentifiers Enabled
  ```

  ```
  Set-NetIPv6Protocol -RandomizeIdentifiers Disabled
  ```

  This can also be done using `netsh interface ipv6`.
- **NetworkManager on Linux** supports RFC 7217 starting with NM v1.2.0, using the connection profile's UUID as part of the seed. This feature is active by default in recent NM versions.

  To enable or disable this feature:

  ```
  nmcli con modify "<profilename>" ipv6.addr-gen-mode stable-privacy
  ```

  ```
  nmcli con modify "<profilename>" ipv6.addr-gen-mode eui64
  ```
- **systemd-networkd** *kind of* supports RFC 7217 using this .network file option, but appears to require you to explicitly list network prefixes for which this mode should be used:

  ```
  [Network]
  IPv6Token=prefixstable:2001:db8:abcd:123::/64
  ```

  If no prefixes match, it will still fall back to EUI-64 method.
- **dhcpcd on Linux/BSD** supports RFC 7217 using this option in /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

  ```
  slaac private
  ```

  To disable this feature and use traditional EUI-64 identifiers:

  ```
  slaac hwaddr
  ```
- **Linux kernel SLAAC** supports RFC 7217 as of Linux v4.1.0; however, it must be manually activated by storing the secret seed via sysctl.

  The secret key is a 128-bit hexadecimal string (shaped like an IPv6 address), which you can generate using:

  ```
  uuidgen | sed "s/-//g; s/..../:&/g; s/^://"
  ```

  This secret key must be stored in the `net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret` sysctl. To make it persistent, it could be put in `/etc/sysctl.d/50-rfc7217.conf` or similar file:

  ```
  net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret = 84a0:d5aa:52b0:4d35:k567:3aa6:7af5:474c
  ```

  Setting the secret automatically activates this mode for all network interfaces. To check whether the feature is active, look for "addrgenmode stable_secret" in `ip -d link`, or the value "2" in `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.<ifname>.addr_gen_mode`.

#### Temporary private addresses

This feature (defined in [RFC 4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941)) provides *additional* addresses which are generated randomly and rotated every few hours. These addresses are used for outgoing connections only – you still retain your MAC-based or RFC7217-based primary address for incoming connections.

- **Windows** supports temporary addresses as of Windows XP SP2.

  To enable/disable this feature:

  ```
  netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=enabled
  netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled
  ```

  Note that Windows now supports hash-based primary address generation starting with Vista, so this feature isn't as critical.
- **NetworkManager on Linux**: Recent versions of NetworkManager handle RA on their own, although the two values below have identical meanings to sysctl (2 = prefer privacy address, 1 = prefer main address):

  ```
   nmcli con modify <name> ipv6.ip6-privacy 2
  ```

  Note that NetworkManager now supports RFC7217-based primary address generation starting with v1.2.0, so this feature isn't as important.

  Side note: As of 1.4.0, NM allows randomizing the MAC address itself, too. Set `wifi.cloned-mac-address` to `stable` to have a different MAC for every network (recommended), or `random` to randomize it for *every* connection (may cause problems).

  In all cases, `<name>` must be the connection name, e.g. WiFi SSID or `"Wired Connection 1"`. Use `nmcli con` to list all.

  To make this the default for *new* connections, as of 1.2.0 you can change `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

  ```
   [connection]
   ipv6.addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
   wifi.cloned-mac-address=stable
  ```
- **dhcpcd** supports temporary address using the `slaac ... temporary` sub-option:

  ```
   slaac private temporary
  ```

  or

  ```
   slaac hwaddr temporary
  ```
- **Linux kernel SLAAC** supports temporary addresses, but does not use them by default. They can be activated by setting these sysctls:

  ```
   sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=2
   sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=2
  ```

  The `all` or `default` part can be replaced with a specific interface name; e.g. `net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr`.

  *(I used `ip link set eth0 down && ip link set eth0 up` to force an address assignment, but you can also run `rdisc6 eth0` or just wait a few minutes for the next periodic Router Advertisement.)*
- **Mac OS X** – enabled by default since OS X 10.7 Lion:

  ```
   sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.use_tempaddr=1
  ```

  Temporary addresses, if enabled, will be preferred.
- **FreeBSD**:

  ```
   sysctl net.inet6.ip6.use_tempaddr=1
   sysctl net.inet6.ip6.prefer_tempaddr=1
  ```
- **Older NetBSD versions**:

  ```
   sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.use_tempaddr=1
  ```

  Latest NetBSD appears to no longer have kernel SLAAC support, in which case follow dhcpcd instructions instead.
- **OpenBSD** – support added in [5.2](http://www.openbsd.org/52.html); enabled and preferred by default in [5.3](http://www.openbsd.org/53.html).

  ```
   ifconfig em0 autoconfprivacy
  ```

  `ifconfig` shows "autoconfprivacy" next to temporary addresses.

Notes on configuration:

- **On Linux, OS X, and all BSDs, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make the setting permanent.**
- On Windows, the changes will persist automatically. *(You can append `store=active` to the `netsh` command if you want it to only last until reboot.)*

---

Partially based on [IPv6 Operating Systems](http://ipv6int.net/systems/) at IPv6INT.net. See also [General IPv6 Notes](https://wikispaces.psu.edu/display/ipv6/General+IPv6+Notes)

---

If the hardware address is used in the IPv6 address, it usually means your network uses IPv6 Stateless Autoconfiguration. In such case, you can simply pick your own address suffix and configure IPv6 manually.

However, even though the manually added address will not have your hardware info, it will still be static (unlike with Privacy Addressing, which changes addresses every so often). Also, static addresses can be a pain in a network larger than 2-3 devices.

Comment: Nice side effect on my Mac and a FRITZ!Box 7340 router: I get two addresses in `ifconfig`. Outgoing connections use the random `autoconf temporary` address, which changes every now and then. Good! But for incoming connections (when opened up in my router), I can still use the `autoconf` address. I don't mind exposing that in DNS records (though maybe I could even somehow choose another address for that too).

Comment: Ahh, after [whois-spamming](http://www.erik-rasmussen.com/blog/2006/12/05/whois-spam/) we now get IPv6 spamming: [dig -t AAAA www.v6.facebook.com](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/dig.php?domain=-t+AAAA+www.v6.facebook.com) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: IPv6 addresses along the lines of `de4d:b33f` aren't that bad for memorizing; also, they're put in place by their owner, whereas `whois` spam is a) annoying and b) caused by outsiders who don't have control of your domain.

Comment: As an aside: it seems (some of) the above might tell the OS to *prefer* the temporary address, [but applications could still override this preference](http://superuser.com/questions/645205/disable-ipv6-autoconf-mac-based-ipv6-address-without-disabling-privacy-address).

Comment: AFAICS using temporary addresses (IPv6 privacy) is effectively unusable with some ISPs due to router advertisements with an absurd short max lifetime of 40s, which overrides the kernel settings.  Linux see `ip a` for `preferred_lft`.  So `ssh` connections will break each 40s if you enable this feature.  It's not even usable for normal web-surfers, as each download must be finished within 40s as well.

Comment: @Tino: They won't. `preferred_lft` only defines when the address should be used for _new outgoing_ connections, but when it expires, the address still remains valid for the `valid_lft` time. So even in a normal situation, when a temporary address stops being preferred after 10 hours (and a new one is generated), it will still remain valid for around a week.

Comment: @Tino: So this is only a problem when the routers set maximum _valid_ lifetime to 40 seconds. **This would break regular (non-privacy) SLAAC addresses too,** in exactly the same way. (Though I'm not sure if it does – I think I remember setting mine to 30 seconds, just a bit higher than the advertisement interval, and it would just refresh every time an advertisement was received. I may be wrong.)

Comment: @grawity: That is exactly what my ISP does.  My ISP's router nails (unchangable) `preferred_lft` to 30s and `maximum_lft` (or what it's called) to 40s.  `SLAAC` is unaffected because the `MAC` does not change, so the IP stays the same after refresh.  The privacy address *may* change,  Kernels seem to differ here and I don't know why (yet).  On Debian with a 2.6.x kernel, the IP changes each 30s (and is approx. 45s usable), while on a crrent Ubuntu the address changes only with reboots (AFAICS) when I enable privacy.

Comment: IMO you should switch the `sysctl` commands for instructions on adding to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or, on Arch Linux, `/etc/sysctl.d/any_file_name`). Lots of people may be busy and not read the whole post. Also, people will very rarely want to make this change just until the next reboot.

Comment: Heads up! If your ISP gives you a dynamic prefix, RFC 7217 won't work as intended. Since the interface identifier (the suffix) is based on your ISP-provided prefix to produce global unicast addresses, it will change every time your prefix changes.

Comment: @user1686 do you happen to know if you are able to *disable* the privacy rules in Linux for a specific prefix on a given interface but leave them on for other prefixes? I am interested because in my ULA prefix on some machines I would like the address to be stable and not change. Whereas for the prefix provided by my ISP, then I would like that to change.

Comment: **systemd-networkd** can now use [stable private addresses without specifying a prefix](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/16618); the [configuration key has changed](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/a73628e647b15b83bfcc49cb554c0ab31a4045ea) as well. Set `Token=prefixstable` in the `[IPv6AcceptRA]` section (or `[DHCPPrefixDelegation]` if using prefix delegation).

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this only applies to certain IP addressing schemes. More than likely you (or your ISP) are using IPv6 autoconfiguration, which requires a fairly large block of IPs to accomplish in the first place. The solution could be to turn this feature off. Your ISP might use DHCP to assign addresses as well, which is still possible with IPv6.

Comment: As for large blocks: according [to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#IPv6_address_space) in "General allocation": *RIRs assign smaller blocks to ISPs, which then distribute this in /48 sized parts to their clients.* Indeed, my ISP also assigns /48 prefixes to consumer-grade subscribers. Not too odd then?

Comment: A single /48 will be sufficient for every last customer they have until the end of time, regardless of growth (2^80 hosts!). While this might seem like overkill, it certainly makes routing simple. A /96 network would be sufficient to provide IP addresses for the entire IPv4 internet. Any network smaller than a /64 wouldn't allow MAC autoconfiguration.

Comment: I mean that *I myself* have a /48 block for my Macs, printer, Squeezebox, fridge and toaster, and whatever other 2^80 machines I decide to hook up. And so do all other subscribers at my ISP. And all of that appears to be quite common according to Wikipedia.

Comment: eh, what? I can't even think of a reason to assign a /64 to a single residential client (beyond autoconfiguration, and even that is pointless), let alone a /48. They say that the only possible reason for IP exhaustion in IPv6 would be astonishingly poor address allocation, and it looks like your ISP qualifies.

Comment: Then blame Wikipedia, and Arin's draft [IPv6 Addressing Plans](http://www.getipv6.info/index.php?title=IPv6_Addressing_Plans&oldid=2998): *All customers get one /48 unless they can show that they need more than 65k subnets.* But also: *If you have lots of consumer customers you may want to assign /56s to private residence sites* — which still is more than I *ever* need. ;-) But, things might change: my ISP never *promised* this, though obviously their customers have configured modem/routers based on this.

Comment: I think when Arin says "customer" they mean "ISP". Any ISP (including very, very large ones) can allocate a single /64 for their entire network and be done with it. No further routing required. But allocating blocks of IP addresses numbering in the trillions to joe-average residential customers is downright foolhardy.

Comment: I'm quite sure that's not what that page means, as otherwise *If you have lots of consumer customers you may want to assign /56s to private residence sites* would be pointless? Apart from that: I'm no expert; just quoting what I've linked to, and what I'm using myself.

Comment: Just noticed that the link in my above comment links to a now old version: see [IPv6 Addressing Plans­](http://www.getipv6.info/index.php/IPv6_Addressing_Plans) for the current Arin proposal. No changes in *All customers get one /48 unless they can show that they need more than 65k subnets. [...] If you have lots of consumer customers you may want to assign /56s to private residence sites.* though.

Comment: Apparently, [one reason to assign at least a `/56`](http://superuser.com/questions/788717/debugging-ipv6-routing-issues/788724#788724): *"ISPs that only hand out a single `/64` prevent you from any subnetting at all. If that `/64` is on the WAN interface then you'll never get decent IPv6 on your LAN(s). This is the ISPs fault and they should fix this by giving out a decent amount (`/48` or `/56`) of addresses."*

Comment: A /64 is not "a fairly large block"; it is the _smallest_ reasonable allocation block for a subnet. Several IPv6 features require that a subnet be /64, and you have forgotten (or not realized) that IPv6 was designed in large part to prevent anyone _ever_ running out of addresses ever again. You must free your mind from the old thinking of needing to conserve precious addresses; it has no place in IPv6.

Comment: @Ernie: Not at all. There are enough `/48`s (networks with 2^80 addresses) that each person could have about 40,000. ISPs should be giving out `/56`s at the very least.

Comment: "... free your mind from the old thinking of needing to conserve..." famous last words

Comment: I have a static /56 and use my isps stateless autoconfig and afaik  sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=2
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=2 work since I can't get a reverse dns to stick to the ipv6 addresses which means they can't be the same.