# disable IPv6 autoconf (MAC-based) IPv6 address without disabling privacy addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

Is it possible to configure the Linux kernel to automatically get the [RFC4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941) temporary (privacy) IPv6 addresses without getting the [RFC4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) public (MAC-based) IPv6 address?

With the following sysctl settings on my Ubuntu 13.04 Linux system, I get the temporary IPv6 addresses, but I also get the public MAC-based IPv6 address:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr=2
```

I don't want the MAC-based IPv6 address.  I just want the temporary privacy addresses.  I realize that `use_tempaddr=2` says to *prefer* the temporary address, but applications can still `bind()` to the MAC-based address or use the `IPV6_PREFER_SRC_PUBLIC` sockopt (see [RFC5014](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5014)) to override this preference.  I predict applications like Adobe Flash will allow web sites to have their flash applications phone home using the MAC-based IP, making it that much harder for people to avoid being tracked by marketers (or governments) wherever they go.

With the following sysctl settings:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr=2
```

I get no automatically configured IPv6 addresses.  None.

How do I get temporary IPv6 addresses without getting the MAC-based IPv6 address?

Comment: Richard, just curious: did you ever find a satisfying solution? (Michael's answer may be correct, but I really don't know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no. If you want temporary addresses, you must be using either stateless address autoconfiguration (as you already know) or DHCPv6, which can be configured to [request temporary addresses from the DHCPv6 server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3315#section-12). In your case, DHCPv6 is probably the way you will want to go, and it is what most major ISPs are deploying.

Comment: I'm hoping someone will jump in and prove you wrong, but I think you're right.  :(

Answer (score 1):

With recent kernels (or recent NetworkManager versions), you can enable [RFC 7217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7217) address generation mode, which provides stable addresses based on a secret seed.

#### For autoconfiguration by NetworkManager ≥ v1.2

NetworkManager 1.2 handles autoconf and assigns addresses on its own.

```
$ nmcli con modify "Ethernet" ipv6.addr-gen-mode stable-privacy
```

This can be set for all new connections via `NetworkManager.conf`.

#### For autoconfiguration by the kernel

Older NM versions and non-NM systems rely on the kernel to assign addresses. The new addrgenmode can be activated via sysctl:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret = 1d8b:4da9:888k:5a65:7aaa:7o2d:ce60:ec4e
```

Of course, you'll need to generate your own key instead:

```
$ head -c 16 /dev/urandom | xxd -p | sed "s/..../:&/g; s/://"
```

Use `ip -d link` to make sure "addrgenmode stable_secret" is shown.

Comment: under `busybox` pipe `urandom` into `xxd -p -c 16` (or install `vim` for it's `xxd`)