# How can I see bottom of dialogue box that is offscreen?

Tags: windows-8.1, display, dialog

I've been searching for a way to get to the bottom portion of a dialogue box that spills below the edge of the screen. It's important that I get to it because it's where the *save*, *default*, *cancel* buttons are found. I've tried all sorts of shenanigans with *move* operations but none are working. I have also been looking for a way to make everything smaller but my screen resolution won't allow it (or I don't know if I'm looking in the right place).

I think a lot of people have had problems with actual windows (the ones that are resizable and can be pushed over the top edge) but this is a dialogue box that opens from within another window and I cannot push it further up from the edge.

I already have my taskbar placed to one side. I can confirm the buttons exist with some magnifying glass shenanigans but I have not been able to put them on screen.

OS: Windows 8.1

[image: The dialogue box spills below the edge and cannot be accesed]

Comment: @James alt key huh? I haven't tried that one. The magnifying glass trick: use fullscreen mode and tab through all selectable elements, eventually hitting the ones that are off screen, the screen will scroll as it tries to horizontally center the content. That is how I confirmed such buttons exist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a natively widescreen monitor:

It might sound silly but you need more vertical screen real estate so the only temporary solution would be to rotate your screen by 90 degrees.

Set the orientation to portrait and then reverse the resolution setting. In my screenshot I would need to set the resolution to 1200x1920 if I want to use portrait mode.

[image]

The ultimate solution is to get the software fixed or get a monitor with more vertical pixels.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

This is really annoying and even worse if the title bar is outside of screen, so you cannot drag it.

The workaround I've been using is to install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and use [EasyWindoDrag script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/EasyWindowDrag_%28KDE%29.htm). With that, you can drag the window or resize it by grabbing any part of window (using mouse), no only title bar or a corner. It works on every app I've tried.

As an added bonus, while you see a modal dialog, you can not only move that, but also move other windows of the app, which normally isn't possible.

You should get AHK anyway, [it has a lot of cool stuff](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/).

Comment: Can you give it a try & see if it will drag a window above the top of the screen? That seems to be a sticking point for this window, it will move, but not above/beyond the top of the screen

Comment: The script works by grabbing window by any pixel of the window, not just a corner. If you grab it by a bottom pixel, you can even move pretty most of the window off-screen (apart from the bottom pixel row). It works for all apps I've tried.

Comment: That would be great if it can move the window higher, and it looks like it's open source too, +1

Answer (score 5):

Happens sometimes with programs that use a fixed size of windows, that unfortunately happens to be bigger than your desktop/screen size. Likely a poor programming decision, or written for a different/old version where they assumed a minimum screen size, or some screen setting that could be changed.

- Sometimes the window could be **resized** and it might work
- Maybe could **move** the window (maybe using the keyboard ALT+SPACE and arrow keys) to hide the top instead of the bottom
- While using your magnifying workaround, memorize the number of <kbd>TAB</kbd> presses it takes to get from one known entry to another one. So maybe clicking on the filename entry, then pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> 5 times will bring you to the Save button where you can press space/enter to save, even though you can't "see" it.
- Change your **screen resolution** to something bigger (if there is one available), to fit the window. But that's a "poor"/clunky solution.

  Instructions for 8.1 don't seem to be easily available on the windows.microsoft.com website, but they have Vista & 7, they're very similar so should be very similar for 8.1:

  1. Open Screen Resolution by clicking the "Start button", clicking "Control Panel", and then, under "Appearance and Personalization", clicking "Adjust screen resolution".
  2. Click the drop-down list next to Resolution, move the slider to the resolution you want, and then click Apply.
  3. Click Keep to use the new resolution, or click Revert to go back to the previous resolution.

- Or possibly you're not getting your best possible resolution, possibly see ["Monitor not displaying correct resolution after Windows 8.1 install"](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1846275/monitor-displaying-correct-resolution-windows-install.html) on tomshardware.com (re-install drivers/Catalyst control center).

Or possibly you have **desktop display scaling** that's making your screen look "smaller" than it really is, read an older article ["Hands-On with Windows 8.1: Desktop Display Scaling"](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/hands-windows-81-desktop-display-scaling) that might be relevant.

If you have a second monitor, possibly setting it up to be "above" or "below" could let the extra-tall window "spill over" to the other monitor, but that's just an idea

Best solution's probably getting an updated version of the program that has decent-sized windows. Maybe bug the authors with a bug report, you're probably not the only user with that problem

Comment: I am already bugging software maintainers. Also, this window cannot be resized or moved above the edge not even using the **move window** suggestion. Please expand on **screen resolution**. I have my settings to max-res and no other setting outputs more height than I already have. I don't know if the font-size inside programs is determined by the program itself, if I could change this it might help

Comment: edited a bit, but if it's maxed & drivers don't change it, I'm about out of ideas. Some windows just won't move above the top border, sometimes works on some linux window managers but that's no help to "windows". Your magnification tool/trick is at least a workaround

Comment: I will keep this question on hold for a while. If no better solution comes up then I guess I'm screwed until your last point is a success.

Comment: Had another idea for a "blind tab" work around, with tab & space/enter so many times. The best one to actually see so far might be your magnification one...

Comment: ...and in a burst of great answers he flies past the 2K line! Congrats.

Comment: @fixer1234 I wouldn't necessarily say *great*, but got a few votes, thanks! I can edit things left right & center now. Just rejected a proposed edit to remove the "mac" tag from a 100+ voted Q that starts *"On my macintosh..."* boy oh boy

Comment: @Xen2050 Sorry to meta threadjack, but your comment made me wonder if you read the tag wiki for [mac], which specifies the tag is to be used for issues concerning Mac *hardware*. If the question wasn't about hardware, the edit was probably valid. TMYK

Comment: @Excellll No problem :) Maybe you can help me out with it, it's [this Q](https://superuser.com/questions/243669/how-to-avoid-exposing-my-mac-address-when-using-ipv6): *"On my Macs, each IPv6 address includes the MAC address of a specific computer (not of my router). Sites such as ipv6-test.com not only show it, but even tell me it belongs to an Apple computer..."* So IMO it definitely sounds like it's related to Mac hardware and a specific Apple hardware identifier... so the "Mac" tag, *and* the "mac-address" tags are relevant, & were there for 3+ years (and the blog). What do you think?

Comment: Well, the question isn't about the hardware, it's about ipv6 protocol, so I'd say it doesn't apply. (Just because there is an Apple computer involved doesn't mean the tag is relevant.) Anyway, I see the edit went through, so no worries. Your comment just made my eyebrow shoot up yesterday, and I thought I could share some advice that would help you with future reviews. New reviewers are always welcome! </meta>

Answer (score 2):

if you use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> you can rotate the screen to portrait, select your button, then change it back to normal with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.

Comment: Creative temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Download an app (in Firefox at least) called Infinite Screen.  I had the same [rpblem and this fixes it.  Simply install then hold Cntrl + Shift and move the window around with the touchpad, then  move the screen back to its normal position.

Works every time.

Comment: Please read https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers which talks about how to leave an answer that recommends software.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[AltMove](http://www.deskex.com/AltMove/index.asp)**. Among other features, it can be configured to move and resize windows and controls which can not be normally moved. I've used this a lot on a netbook with a low native resolution, where buttons on windows are frequently placed offscreen.

For example, it can be configured to move a window by holding alt and dragging it with the left mouse button. This will allow you to drag a window up and view its contents that are hidden below.